# Django South - shouldn't it add foreign key & unique relationships to database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have a legacy MySQL database that is used as the foundation for a Django webapp.  It originally used the MyISAM engine for all the tables, but due to foreign key requirements, I changed all the tables to InnoDB, and added Foreign Key and Unique fields to the relevant models.

I'm going to soon export this development database to a production server, so I used South to migrate the data models to the db.  However, I can see that none of the tables have explicit PK, FK and Unique constraints in the table fields themselves, but they show up in the 0001_initial.py file generated by the initial migrations script.

I executed the migration via

```
./manage.py schemamigration app --initial
./manage.py migrate app

Received Table Exists error, reran with --fake flag
./manage.py migrate app --fake
./manage.py migrate app
```

The last command executed with no errors.  So my question is, shouldn't the tables have explicit constraints set after executing a data migration?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a fake migrations it means the migrations are faked in the database.South assumes the migration (The migration in your 0001_initial.py file) is complete.No database changes will happen when you migrate with --fake. You received table exists error because some how the tables you are about to create exists in the database.May be the tables created while you run syncdb.